# GPO Drive Mapping per user

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I would like to know is there a way to map drives for specific users on specific server via GPO? Will item level targeting accomplish this?  I know this can be done for all computers but not sure about specific computers?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know is there a way to map drives for specific users
>   on specific server via GPO? Will item level targeting accomplish this?
>   I know this can be done for all computers but not sure about specific
>   computers?

A combination of Group Policy Preferences drive maps with item level targeting, Loopback policy processing, and Security Filtering should accomplish this.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how one might go about setting that up?  I know item level targeting and security filtering but how would you utilize those for that?